# Using PHP's DOM implementation to return the first 'n' characters of an HTML string

Tags: php, html, dom, xml-parsing, html-parsing

Given an HTML string, I would like to return a modified string with the following properties:

1. The first *n* characters of the text contents (HTML tags aside) should remain.
2. Elements after *n* characters have been met should be removed entirely.
3. If *n* characters is not at the end of an element, text afterwards in the same element should not remain.
4. Tags on elements at and before *n* characters should remain.

Basically, I just want to return a shortened version of the HTML, without the DOM structure being interrupted, and based on the length of the text contents only.

Using PHP's DOM implementation, it seems this will be overly complex. Using a pattern match isn't ideal as the conditions of the modified string might change over time, and it would require rewriting each time.

Am I missing an easier way of doing this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, ignoring the html tags you want the first n chars of content? Of 1 element? of the entire document?

Comment: I want the first n chars of content of the entire document, but without removing tags (but not counting tags as part of the n chars).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"Using PHP's DOM implementation, it seems this will be overly complex."*

**Really?**

Here's a very simple DOM implementation if you want the first 100 characters from inside the `<body>` tag and its child nodes. You could further massage this to remove newline characters and superfluous space/tab characters or check the length of the `$content` string inside the `foreach` to break the loop and stop concatenation once you've reached a certain number of characters.

```
$str = '...';
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($str);
$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body');

$content = '';
foreach($elements as $node){
  foreach($node->childNodes as $child) {
    $content .= $child->nodeValue;
  }
}

echo substr($content, 0, 100);
```

---

**UPDATE**

As per your comment, here's a simple way to count the characters inside HTML nodes and delete all the tags after the specified character limit is reached. Note that you can't perform the delete operation inside the original `foreach` because it causes `DOM` to reindex the nodes and you won't get the results you expect. Instead, we store the nodes we want to delete in an array and delete them after the initial iteration.

```
$str = '...';
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom->preserveWhitespace = FALSE;
$dom->loadHTML($str);

$elements = $dom->getElementsByTagName('body');

$remove   = FALSE;
$maxChars = 100;
$content  = '';
$delete   = array();

foreach($elements as $node){
  foreach($node->childNodes as $child) {
    if ($remove) {
      $delete[] = $child;
    } else {
      $content .= $child->nodeValue;
      if ( ! $remove && strlen($content) >= $maxChars) {
        $remove = TRUE;
      }
    }
  }
}

foreach ($delete as $child) {
  $child->parentNode->removeChild($child);
}

$dom->formatOutput = TRUE;
echo $dom->saveHTML();
```

Comment: Thanks, but this is just the text contents, with all tags removed.

Comment: @melkamo I thought this is what you were looking for. I'm happy to update if you'll clarify what you'd like instead. *"The first n characters of the text contents (HTML tags aside) should remain."*

Comment: Sorry it wasn't clear. I tried stating the differences between the modified and original string without saying to remove the tags. In other words, the node to cut-off the text should be based only on the length of the text contents. But the tags should remain.

Comment: So, just so I understand, you want all the HTML tags removed after you reach a certain character count for all the node values up to that point, leaving the HTML intact otherwise?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I was going to write a function to traverse through each node, child by child, and use a character counter. Then, once it's exceeded, start removing all nodes from the DOM document from there on. But just seemed overkill to me...

Comment: @melkamo Updated answer -- sorry for the slow response, had to do some real work :)

Comment: Thanks :)
I don't quite get the results that I was expecting. I think this may be due to the fact that it goes 2 nodes deep? So I'll need to wrap a function in there somewhere. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @melkamo Yeah, sorry, I was going for simplicity to demonstrate how to do it with DOM. It's definitely because it's only two levels: for something complex you'd probably want to do a recursive function.